# Django REST: get_queryset providing duplicate responses

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a simple online shop app so when you want to buy an item, a button click leads you to the charge api. (ex. item 2 will direct to /api/charge/2)

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from gallery.views import ClothingView
from gallery.api.views import ListClothes
from gallery.api.views import ChargeView

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/<int:num>/', ListClothes.as_view()),
    path('api/charge/<int:num>', ChargeView.as_view(), name='charge_api'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ChargeView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ChargeSerializer
    count = 0

    def get_queryset(self):
        a = ClothingModel.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['num']).first()
        net_price = int(float(a.full_price) * 100)
        if float(a.discount) > 0.00:
            net_price = int(net_price * (1 - (float(a.discount) / 100)))

        self.count += 1

        print(self.count)

        if self.count == 1:

            stripe.api_key = settings.API_KEY
            charge_rtn_body = stripe.Charge.create(    # Create charge object
                amount=net_price,
                currency="usd",
                source="tok_visa", # obtained with Stripe.js
                description= "[Stripe charge] " + a.description.upper()
            )

        return ClothingModel.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['num'])
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ChargeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ClothingModel
        fields = ('full_price', 'discount', 'description')
```

I am creating a charge object for Stripe (payment method) each time the api gets called, but dependent on the clothing item id. So to handle this I use self.kwargs on get_queryset() to link to a clothing item. When I view the charges on my Stripe dashboard after a single click, multiple charges come at once (4 at a time). I have hard coded the `if self.count == 1:` as a work around but know that is not good practice. Is there a reason for these multiple calls in get_queryset() per single request and how can I cleanly implement? Thank you.

Comment: The class is loaded into memory when you start the server and everytime a request is made, an instance of the class is created and hence the count will keep increasing per request. Please put up an explanation of what you want to accomplish and we will be able to help you out better

Comment: Hi Aswin. Thanks for your reply. I want to make sure I can create this stripe.Charge object only once, not 4+ times (I am working around the duplicates with the "if statement" for count == 1). I feel like this logic might be better implemented outside outside of the function but I rely on the "num" I retrieve. Let me know if I can further clarify.

Comment: `get_queryset` is called everytime the view is invoked (even for get requests). And creation of objects should happen ideally in POST requests. So I would move the creation code to the appropriate view function rather than in get_queryset

Comment: Thanks. So how would I still make sure I can get the corresponding <num> that correlates to the api/charge/<num> if I move it outside get_queryset?

Comment: The URL parameters can be accessed from the view function itself. Check: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: Yes I completely forgot about this! Revisiting Django for this app and forgot. Thanks a lot for your help Aswin. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects should be created only in POST requests. `get_queryset` is called everytime a view is invoked (even for GET requests). So the object create should be moved inside the view function. The dynamic part of the URL is accessible from the view function as present here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example

```
class ChargeView(ListCreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request, num):
        charge = ClothingModel.objects.get(id=num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.conf import settings # new
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
import stripe
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'stripe.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): # new
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['key'] = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        return context

def charge(request): # new
    if request.method == 'POST':
        charge = stripe.Charge.create(amount=5000,currency='ind',description='A Django charge',
            source=request.POST['stripeToken'])
        return render(request, 'charge.html')
```